# Addresses of variables in constructor when an object is being inserted in a std::map

Tags: c++, constructor

I really don't understand the outcome of this code:

```
struct exampleClass
{
    double a = 12.1;
    std::map<int, double*> innerMap;

    exampleClass()
    {
        std::cout << "ADR of  variable a in constructor = " << &a << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ADR of this in constructor = " << this << std::endl;
        innerMap.emplace(4,&a);
    }
};


int main(){
    std::map<int, exampleClass> map;
    map.insert(std::make_pair(4, exampleClass{}));


    for (auto& it : map)
    {
        std::cout << "ADR of a = " << &(it.second.a) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Content of a = " << it.second.a << std::endl;
        std::cout << it.second.innerMap.find(4)->second << std::endl;
        std::cout << *(it.second.innerMap.find(4)->second); //the output is wrong
    }
}
```

The outcome is:

```
ADR of  variable a in constructor = 0x7ffee080b500 

ADR of this in constructor = 0x7ffee080b500

ADR of a = 0x559ddb2c42e8

Content of a = 12.1

0x7ffee080b500

6.95312e-310
```

I do not understand why the addresses in the `for` loop differ from the addresses in the constructor. Also the "constructor address" is used for inserting in the `innerMap`, which causes a bug.

Can someone explain this to me?

What confuses me additionally is that the following works as expected:

```
exampleClass abc{};
std::cout << "ADR of a = " << &(abc.a)<< std::endl;
std::cout << *(abc.innerMap.find(4)->second) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
map.insert(std::make_pair(4, exampleClass{}));
```

a temporary instance of `exampleClass` was created, with `exampleClass::innerMap` correctly pointing to that instance's `exampleClass::a`. But, immediately afterwards, it is moved around - through the pair into `map`. The contents of `exampleClass::innerMap` remain the same, i.e. the pointer mapped to `4` is the same, but after the temporary instance is gone, it becomes invalid.

Solution: fix the semantics of copy/move constructor of your class while adhering to [the rules of three/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). The only thing you can figure out there is to use `new`/`delete` for these pointers everywhere. But we don't do that. If `a` is meant to be a default shared among all instances of the class, it should be `static`. That way, it would outlive all instances and this problem wouldn't exist. Otherwise, use smart pointers.

Comment: Keep in mind that this technically follows the rule of 0/3/5, since there is no copy constructor, move constructor, copy operator=, move operator=, or destructor. Thus, it technically follows the rule.

Comment: @Chipster Okay, having defaulted all the other constructors in this case is the root of the problem. The rule is just something more to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

According to the first answer a self-written move constructor is missing since std::make_pair() calls a default move constructor which does not take care of the special situation. The following move constructor would solve the problem:

```
exampleClass(exampleClass&& other)
{
    this->innerMap.insert(std::make_pair(4, &(this->a)));
}
```